# Classification in the data frame

Tags: r

I've got a data frame:

```
x <- runif(3, 0.0, 0.99)
y <- runif(3, 0.0, 0.99)
df <- data.frame(x, y)
```

| x | y |
| --- | --- |
| 0.32 | 0.68 |
| 0.8 | 0.2 |
| 0.6 | 0.4 |

I would like to classify into a new column such that:
if value 'x' (or 'y') > 0.8 then 'A', 'x'>=0.5 and 'x'<=0.8 then 'B'.
If the value is below 0.5 it will grade as 'C'.
Then this classified value ('A' or 'B') will be in the new 'z' column.

Comment: are you creating the new column from x or y?

Comment: I want to create a 'z' column in the 'df' dataframe based on the calculations in 'x' and 'y'.
In first row of dataframe will be: 0.32, 0.68, 'C' ('C' is from 'z' column

Comment: why should it be C? y>0.5 but less than 0.8. Only if you are using `x` instead of `y` You cannot use both unless you do some operations eg add, subtract multiply etc

Comment: my bad, of course will be 'B'

Comment: Why B? x<0.5. You need to define what to be used. You cannot claim to use both x and Y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry if my answer cannot meet the assumptions, but i think something like this:

```
library(dplyr)

x <- c(0.32, 0.8, 0.6)
y <- c(0.68, 0.2, 0.4)
df <- data.frame(x, y)

df %>%
  mutate(
    z = case_when(
    x >= 0.8 | y >= 0.8 ~ "A",
    x >= 0.5 | y < 0.8 ~ "B",
    x < 0.5 & y < 0.5 ~ "C")
    )

     x    y z
1 0.32 0.68 B
2 0.80 0.20 A
3 0.60 0.40 B
```